# CSS adjacent sibling selector fails when parent element class is added

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle demonstrating issue](https://jsfiddle.net/gdLfa38b/)

This works perfectly

```
.content-wrapper.row-fluid + .footer.row-fluid {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

This successfully targets the sibling correctly only on page with body classed `path-frontpage`

```
.path-frontpage .footer.row-fluid {}
```

And this works for the div above footer on page with body classed `path-frontpage`

```
.path-frontpage .content-wrapper.row-fluid {}
```

But this does not set the footer margin-top to zero on page with body classed `path-frontpage`.  Chrome inspector shows the first rule is in effect.  Why? Or rather - how do I get the margin negated just on pages with body class `path-frontpage` ?

```
.path-frontpage .content-wrapper.row-fluid + .path-frontpage .footer.row-fluid {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True usage

```
.path-frontpage .content-wrapper.row-fluid + .footer.row-fluid {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

For your code to work, html should was like this.

```css
div { border:1px solid #ff0000; height: 30px; }

.content-wrapper.row-fluid + .footer.row-fluid {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.path-frontpage .content-wrapper.row-fluid + .path-frontpage .footer.row-fluid {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body class="path-frontpage">
<div class="content-wrapper row-fluid">wrapper
</div>
<div class="path-frontpage"> <!-- I added -->
<div class="footer row-fluid">footer
</div>
</div>
</body>
```